# Why are weak Cipher Suites still in use by clients, particularly mobile apps?

Tags: tls, md5, rc4, ciphers

I am examining the collection of cipher suites that some mobile apps use (Client Hello) and I noticed that the majority of them include the `TLS_RC4_128_MD5` and `TLS_RC4_128_SHA`. According to the OWASP Transport Layer Protection Cheat Sheet https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet, RC4 and MD5 are considered weak and shouldn't be used any more. Therefore I am wondering why developers keep using them?

Thank you

Comment: One of the reason I can think of is to support older devices.

Comment: @mike-stokkel Doesn't that however make them vulnerable against the TLS protocol downgrade attack ? I noticed that even a banking app is using it.

Comment: Remember that the client hello is only a suggestion.  The client suggests, the server chooses.  So, while a client may say *hey, I accept weak ciphers!" as long as it also supports strong ciphers, the server can choose to use strong ciphers instead, and does not, in fact, need to support weak ciphers at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Developers aren't deliberately using them.  Developers are developing applications using whatever the defaults for that platform are, and the defaults are now and have always strongly favored "never cause a user to notice something to complain to us about" over "reduce the chance the user gets hacked".

Additionally, older clients and libraries rarely if ever get updated, since they are "no longer supported" despite being in widespread use because OS developers, library developers, device manufacturers, developers, and users are all unwilling to upgrade and/or change defaults.

- [Java 8](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Java&version=8u31) still supports weak suites by default.
- [IE 11 on Win 7](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=IE&version=11&platform=Win%207) still supports RC4 by default, while I[E 11 on Win 8.1](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=IE&version=11&platform=Win%208.1) does not by default.

[And so on](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html).